# Проблема с шейкерной сортировкой

Tags: c

Недавно начал учить С. По задаче нужно сортировать стипендию от большего к меньшему шейкерной сортировкой. Написал функцию sortCoc (4 пункт в меню), она не работает. Ниже прикрепляю весь код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define N 30


int u8printf(char *fmt,...){
va_list ap;
va_start(ap,fmt);
    int n=mbstowcs(0,fmt,0);
    if(n==-1) return -1;
    wchar_t wfmt[n+1];
    mbstowcs(wfmt,fmt,n+1);
    for(int m=128;m<=32768;m*=2){
        wchar_t wbuf[m];
        int r=vswprintf(wbuf,m,wfmt,ap);
        if(r!=-1) {
            char buf[m*4];
            wcstombs(buf,wbuf,m*4);
            fputs(buf,stdout);
            return r;
        }
    }
    return -1;
va_end(ap);
}
struct persons { 
char name[30]; 
char secondName[30];
char thirdName[30]; 
char fac[15];
int age; 
int fee;

}; 


void sortSecondName(struct persons array[], int n);
void sortCoc(struct persons array[], int n);
void vyvids(struct persons array[], int n);
struct persons newElement();
int main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    struct persons personArray[N] = {
{"Богдан","Корнієнко", "Віталійович", "ІХФ", 17, 1500}, {"Віталій", "Цаль", "Сергієвич", "ТЕФ", 19, 970}, {"Валерія", "Козак", "Олексіївна", "ІПСА", 18, 900}, {"Іван", "Мельник", "Олександрович", "ФІОТ", 19, 2250}, {"Юрій", "Білоус", "Романович", "ТЕФ", 20, 400}
};
int n = 5, ind = 1;

vyvids(personArray, n);
int menuRow;
do {
    
    printf("\n1. Відобразити дані користувачей\n2. Доповнити таблицю користувачей\n3. Сортирувати таблицю за призвіщем\n4. Сортирувати таблицю за степендією\n5. Закінчити программу\n\nОберіть пункт меню: ");
    scanf("%d", &menuRow);
    
    switch (menuRow)
    {
    case 1: vyvids(personArray, n); break;
    case 2: n++; personArray[n - 1] = newElement(); break;
    case 3: sortSecondName(personArray, n); vyvids(personArray, n); break;
    case 4: sortCoc(personArray, n); vyvids(personArray, n); break;
    case 5: ind = 0; break;
    default:
        printf("Невідомий пункт меню\n\n");
        break;
    }

} while (ind);

return 0;
}

void sortSecondName(struct persons array[], int n) {
   int j, i = 0;
   struct persons t;

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
       for (j = i; j > 0; j--)
           if (strcmp(array[j - 1].secondName, array[j].secondName) > 0) {
               t = array[j - 1];
               array[j - 1] = array[j];
               array[j] = t;
           }
    
}

struct persons newElement() {

struct persons person;
printf("Новий користувач\n");
  fgets(person.secondName, sizeof(person.secondName), stdin);
person.secondName[strlen(person.secondName) - 1] = '\0';
printf("Введіть прізвище користувача: ");
fgets(person.secondName, sizeof(person.secondName), stdin);
person.secondName[strlen(person.secondName) - 1] = '\0';
printf("Введіть ім'я користувача: ");
fgets(person.name, sizeof(person.name), stdin);
person.name[strlen(person.name) - 1] = '\0';
printf("Введіть по-батькові користувача: ");
fgets(person.thirdName, sizeof(person.thirdName), stdin);
person.thirdName[strlen(person.thirdName) - 1] = '\0';
printf("Введіть факультет користувача: ");
fgets(person.fac, sizeof(person.fac), stdin);
person.fac[strlen(person.fac) - 1] = '\0';
printf("Введіть вік користувача: ");
scanf("%d", &person.age);
printf("Введіть степендію користувача: ");
scanf("%d", &person.fee);
return person;
}
void swap99(a, b) {
int temp = a; 
  a = b; 
  b = temp;

}
void sortFee(struct persons array[], int n) {

struct persons person;
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < (n - 1) - i; j++)
        if (array[j].fee < array[j + 1].fee) {
            person = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j + 1];
            array[j + 1] = person;
        }

}
void sortCoc(struct persons array[], int n) {

struct persons person;
int top, bottom, last_swap;
  top = 0;
  bottom = n;
while (top < bottom) {
last_swap = 0;
for (int i = top; top < bottom; i++) {
  if (array[i].fee > array[i+1].fee) {
    swap99(array[i].fee, array[i+1].fee);
    last_swap = i;
  }
}
bottom = last_swap;
for (int j = bottom; bottom < top; j--) {
  if (array[j].fee > array[j-1].fee) {
    swap99(array[j].fee, array[j-1].fee);
    last_swap = j;
      }
    }
  }

}
void vyvids(struct persons array[], int n) {

int i;
printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -\n");
printf("|                                     Дані користувачів                                      |\n");
printf("|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n");
printf("|            Прізвище|                 Ім'я|          По-батькові|  Факультет|   Вік|   Степ.|\n");
printf("|--------------------|---------------------|---------------------|-----------|------|--------|\n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    u8printf("|%20s|%21s|%21s|%11s|%6d|%8d|\n", array[i].secondName,
        array[i].name, array[i].thirdName, array[i].fac, array[i].age, array[i].fee);
}


printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Куча ошибок. Сначала функция `swap` - пытаетесь обменять локальные переменные. А надо менять по указателю. Сортировка с обратым ходом у вас недописана, всё скопировано необдуманно и бессмысленно. В вашем примере не добавлены необходимые библиотеки. Вот все переделки :

```
// библиотеки нужны
# include <stdarg.h>
# include <wchar.h>

// меняем значения по указателю
void swap99(int * a,int * b) {
int temp = *a; 
  *a = *b; 
  *b = temp;
}

void sortCoc(struct persons array[], int n) {
int top, bottom, last_swap;
  top = 0;
  bottom = n;
while (top < bottom) {
last_swap = 0;
// сравнивать нужно индекс i , а не bottom
// цикл на один элемент меньше, потому,
// что обращаетесь к array[i+1].fee
for (int i = top; i < bottom-1; i++) {
  if (array[i].fee > array[i+1].fee) {
    // меняем значения по указателю
    swap99(&(array[i].fee), &(array[i+1].fee));
    // индекс bottom должен быть больше последнего на один
    last_swap = i+1;
  }
}
bottom = last_swap;
// сравнивать нужно индекс j , а не bottom 
// не меньше, а больше
for (int j = bottom-1; j > top; j--) {
  // чтобы j элемент был больше чем j-1 
  // нужно сравнивать не [j]>[j-1] а [j]<[j-1]
  if (array[j].fee < array[j-1].fee) {
    swap99(&(array[j].fee), &(array[j-1].fee));
    last_swap = j;
      }
    }
// забыли индекс top поменять
top = last_swap ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение

Comment: Если ответ устроил, отметьте галочкой, что ответ принят.